# How can I use ediff (emacs diff) as a diff/merge tool in Windows ClearCase?

Tags: configuration, emacs, diff, clearcase

I'm forced to use ClearCase (Windows version) at work, and I want to use emacs ediff as a diff and merge tool. The problem with the ClearCase map file is that it requires .exe files - I've tried to specify a batch file calling `ediff` and it didn't work.

I don't want to write a C/C++ program (it's been more than 10 years since I've coded anything in C for Win32) that will call `ediff` with the proper arguments. Is there a simpler way?

#### See also:

[Any way to use a custom diff tool with cleartool/clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437)

Comment: @Eddie: the question you link is not a direct answer (plus this is precisely the link I mention in my answer), and Eugene's question is much more specific.

Comment: @Eugene: how about making a .exe from your .bat ? I have added a link a the end of my answer.

Comment: @Eugene: added the link to a utility to transform .bat in .exe, plus the right arguments to look for in that batch. I managee to launch WinMerge through this .bat (since I do not have Emacs to test it). It works though the CLI, not through ClearCase Explorer...

Comment: @Eugene: again, I did not manage to make it work from ClearCase explorer... Did you had more luck on that front ? From the command line, it works though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437), the map file allows you to call an external diff tool.

For Windows, you should try first [to call emacs in ediff mode](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/msg/2e85eb36ec291ebe):

```
   emacs --eval "(ediff-files \"file_1\" \"file_2\")"
```

or

```
   xemacs -eval "(ediff-files \"file_1\" \"file_2\")"
```

(should invoke a *new instance* of XEmacs ediff)

If this works, you may write a `.bat` file called by the map file, and building the appropriate "`emacs ediff`" command line.

Something [along the lines](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about178715.html) of:

```
@echo off
set local
if !%XEMACS_PATH%!==!! SET
XEMACS_PATH=C:\<XEmacs-Path>\i586-pc-win32
set FILE1=%~1
set FILE2=%~2
REM * Bad habit - working on administrative shares.. Why is $->$$ not needed?
REM SET FILE1=%FILE1:$=$$%
REM SET FILE2=%FILE2:$=$$%
REM * Escaping backslash..
SET FILE1=%FILE1:\=\\%
SET FILE2=%FILE2:\=\\%

"%XEMACS_PATH:"=%\gnudoit.exe" "(ediff \"%FILE1%\" \"%FILE2%\")"
```

If map file is not at ease with calling a .bat file, simply [generate an `.exe` from your `.bat`](http://www.commentcamarche.net/telecharger/telechargement-34057824-bat-to-exe-converter).

---

I have done some tests and it turns out:

- "compare with previous version" actually calls:

  `cleartool diff -graphical -pred myFile`
- calling the .bat through a cmd.exe call does not work

  `c:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\lib\mgrs\map`

  `text_file_delta xcompare "c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\cc\test.bat"`

  `cleartool: Error: Operation "xcompare" unavailable for manager "text_file_delta"`
  `(Operation pathname was: "C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\lib\mgrs\"c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\cc\test.bat"")`
- transforming the .bat in .exe does work
- arg2 (`%2`) and arg4 (`%4`) are what you are looking for, with arg5 (`%5`) the name of the temporary file created for the content of the previous version (for snapshot view which can not access extended path name)

So the following bat (transformed in exe) works **from the command-line only** (not from the ClearCase Explorer: DrWatson):

```
"C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" %4 %5
```

You should be able to adapt it to Xemacs, but [Alex's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658127/how-can-i-use-ediff-emacs-diff-as-a-diff-merge-tool-in-windows-clearcase/658436#658436) ([working with Clearcase from Emacs](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsClearCase.html)) might be another more practical solution.

Comment: It was the first thing I've tried, but it seems that CC doesn't like batch files in map. I can switch from builtin diff and merge tools to WinMerge or KDiff with ease, because they're .exe files, but when I specify a batch file, CC doesn't call it ever. I'll try again though.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, my working day is already over. :) I'll add a comment or edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use clearcase package as described [here](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsClearCase.html)

Comment: Hi! Didn't know that you're also lurking here. :)
I'm already using CC package. But sometimes I need to compare files in CC explorer or compare two versions selected in a CC tree version view.

Also Emacs CC mode doesn't handle merges AFAIK. Also it's useless when working in another IDE.