# How to get cleartool diff to return to command line while diff viewer is still open?

Tags: shell, cygwin, dos, clearcase, cleartool

As described in one of the answers to SO question "[Any way to use a custom diff tool with cleartool/clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase)" I have installed WinMerge and a single diff opens fine in WinMerge based on a command of the form

cleartool diff -g filename filename@@clearcase-virtual-path-to-version-I-want-to_compare-to

But when I run that command in cygwin, it does not return to the command prompt until I exit WinMerge.

I want to execute a few such commands from a .bat file or shell script (one for each file in the change set of a given ClearCase activity) and have it either open multiple WinMerge instances, or multiple windows in a single WinMerge instance.

I was able to do that once but I've forgotten how. Can someone remind me?

I sense that this is not really a ClearCase question, but perhaps a DOS or shell question about spawning processes from the cygwin command line ...

Comment: Just completed my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: I am not aware of any formal specifications for the map file. You can try create a custom exe (I have not test that approach). The constraints I mentioned are from direct experimentations.

Comment: Most tries with some options returned: `"cleartool: Error: Operation "compare" unavailable for manager "text_file_delta" (Operation pathname was: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs\"WinMergeU.exe /s ")`

Comment: @VonC thanks for all your help too -- if I get time to try the custom exe I'll let you and all know the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an ampersand at the end of the line to run it in the background:

```
cleartool diff -g filename filename@@clearcase-virtual-path-to-version-I-want-to_compare-to &
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Winmerge Command Line man page](http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/CommandLine.html)

> /s limits WinMerge windows to a single instance. For example, if WinMerge is already running, a new compare opens in the same instance. Without this parameter, multiple windows are allowed: depending on other settings, a new compare might open in the existing window or in a new window.

So you could call WinMerge multiple time:

- either through a background process (like [troelskn suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936313/how-to-get-cleartool-diff-to-return-to-command-line-while-diff-viewer-is-still-op/1936328#1936328))
- or through a DOS `call`

  call  "c:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" /s ...

should be able to launch only one WinMerge instance and continue the DOS script.

---

Note: this does not work with the [`map` file I mention in this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437), since a `map` file needs:

- an executable (`.bat` or `.cmd` will not work)
- no options (`WinMergeU.exe` works, `WinMergeU.exe /s` will not)

Comment: @VonC since you answered the other SO question about WinMerge, referenced in my question, I feel ok asking for this clarification here on this "thread" since you brought up the '/s' switch for WinMerge. My question is -- if I'm using troelskn's suggestion and depending on my WinMerge entry in the ClearCase map file to open WinMerge, exactly how do I add the '/s' into the map file so that it will work as you describe? I tried just adding ' /s' on the end of my 

text_file_delta  xcompare   C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe

line but I got an error.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your note. Where should I look to see the exact requirements of a ClearCase map file, from which you took these constraints? I'm wondering if I can name a batch file .exe to work? Or could I / do I have to write, compile, and link a simple program in C that simply calls WinMergeU.exe /s and call _that_ WinMergeU_slash_s.exe?