# How to best set up Mercurial on a Clearcase static view? (Set up "checkout" hooks?)

Tags: mercurial, clearcase

I'd like to set up a mercurial repository in a clearcase static view directory.  My plan is to clone from that directory, do all my real work in a mercurial repo and then push my changes back to the shared Hg/Clearcase dir.

I'd like to hear general suggestions on how this might work best, but I foresee one specific problem: Clearcase locks files as read-only until they are checked-out.  They way I'd like it to work is to set up a mercurial hook to checkout the file before the push is completed and roll-back the push if the checkout doesn't work.

Should I be looking at the pretxncommit hook?  Or the pull hook?  Also, I'm not quite clear on how to write the actual hooks either.  I know the clearcase command, but I'm not sure how to contruct the hook to pass in the filename for each file in the changeset.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The question I just answered 2 days ago: [How to bridge git to ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342131/how-to-bridge-git-to-clearcase/2342164#2342164) can gives you an illustration of the process.

I like to take the ClearCase checkout/checkin step separate from the DVCS work:
I will unlock files as I need them within the DVCS repo (made *directly* within the snapshot view), and then update the snapshot view, which will tells me the "hijacked" files (which I can the easily checkout and checkin through the cleartool update GUI).

But if you have clone you DVCS repo somewhere else, and push it back to a local repo which is not the ClearCase snapshot view, what you could do is simply copy back the `view.dat` hidden file of your snapshot view at the root directory of the DVCS repo.
That simple file is enough to transform back the local repo in a ClearCase snashot view!
Then you make all the files read-only (except those modified after a certain date, i.e. the time when you started working), to avoid ClearCase considering *all* the files as hijacked.
The rest is similar to the first approach: update, checkout/checkin.

Comment: I considered the hijacked file approach (i.e. not doing any special configuration), and while I think it's a good starting point, there are reasons that a checkout might fail and it would be nice to know that before a push succeeds.  Also, thanks for the nugget about the view.dat!