# ClearCase to Git migration

Tags: git, migration, clearcase, revision-history

We are working on converting our CC Vobs to GIT we have both base and UCM vobs, I have seen many topic with no clear steps.

Is there any tool or steps that can keep history and branches?

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no ClearCase to Git bridge, convertor or adaptor that I know of (retaining the *full* history, with all its events).

It is best to:

- restrict a git repo to an UCM component (while a Vob can contain multiple component and be way too big for a Git repo to handle)
- add in a git repo only the last few baselines of a given components (see "[Equivalent of the clearcase baseline and clearcase activities in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21160387/6309)")
- keep ClearCase in read-only mode for history archive.

You will find a similar advice in:

- "[Save history from Clearcase to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12411240/6309)"
- "[Sync GIT and ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2478707/6309)"

You can try:

- a more elaborate method in "[How to bridge git to ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342131/6309)"
- the [`git-cc` project](https://github.com/charleso/git-cc) (might be obsolete by now)