# What needs to be considered for a Clearcase to GIT migration?

Tags: git, clearcase

I would like to migrate from base Clearcase to GIT without missing any directory.

Is there any process for this?

Does any tool supports this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[ClearCase to Git migration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967852/6309)", there is no simple process, especially when you consider a ClearCase Vob can be huge, and include binaries, as opposed to a Git repo which should be smaller, and without (or with very few) binaries.

As an illustration of that "not so simple" process, [clearvision-cm.com](http://www.clearvision-cm.com/consulting/migrate-to-git/) proposes a *consulting* offer (as opposed to a tool) in order to migration from ClearCase to Git.

Comment: Appreciated your response and thanks for the solution....@@@VonC

Comment: And I hope clearcase export and  GIT import well suited for the base CC to GIT migration....