# Moving from clearcase to git. Need to dump history

Tags: clearcase

I have a clearcase repository and I am planning to move it to git. Is there a way I can dump all the history?

Comment: By dump do you mean remove history?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClearCase to Git migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967817/clearcase-to-git-migration)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my old answer "[ClearCase to Git migration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967852/6309)" (2014), and by contrast with the 2016 "[Git - ClearCase methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37050902/6309)", I would add (2016):

You need to check:

- the nature of the import (is is a full ClearCase vob) or well defined ClearCase folder you want to imports?
- are you working with ClearCase UCM or non-UCM?
- Do you have some labels (or UCM baselines) in the history of your ClearCase Vob?

Only labelled (or baselined) ClearCase versions can be safely imported into a git repo, as they are similar to git commits.

---

The other approach is to actually dump the history (ie not keep it in the new git repo), keep said history in ClearCase (in read-only mode for archive).

Then the solution is simple: go to a ClearCase snapshot view, do a `git init .`, then `git add .`, `git commit -m "first import"`.
You can the add a remote (to an empty bare repo), push and you are done.

```
git remote add origin /url/to/bar/repo
# for instance
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
# or an internal server to your company
git remote add origin https://mycompany.com/gitlab/<project>/<repo>

git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. I did not understand the first question. I am using UCM-Clearcase. Yes I have labels and UCM baselines.

Comment: @RitwikPaul Then the answer stands: import one UCM component per git repo, one baseline at a time (from the oldest baseline to the newest)