# Clear Case to Git swarm Code base movement

Tags: git, repository, gitlab, clearcase, gitswarm

I have to move code base from  Clear Case  to Git swarm. Inside the code there are lot of absolute path references  based on /vobs/....    How to handle this scenario in this task with out code change ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

> But there are lot of absolute path references based on `/vobs/`
>   How to handle this scenario in this task without code change?

Moving a ClearCase repo to a Git repo can be done without referencing any view path (like a dynamic view set with cleartool setview, and accessed through /vobs).
See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537412/6309).

But "inside the code",that does not seem to be a ClearCase or [GitSwarm](https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/gitswarm-overview) issue, more an issue with the *content* (scripts referencing `/vobs/...` in them)
You might need to artificially create a `/vobs/` folder on the host where you clone/checkout a Git repo, in order to find back a path compatible with your scripts. If needed, /vobs/ can be a **[symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951752/6309)** to your checked out repo.
That would respect the "without code change" part of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. Suppose if I create a /vobs folder . Still the script will refer absolute path starting with /vobs as root (I use Linux machine to build) . But for the checked out folder vobs folder is just a parent folder path wont start with /vobs . right? Any solutions for that

Comment: @Refinath Yes: symlink (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951752/6309): /vobs/ would symlink to your repo root folder.

Comment: does symbolic link  work while building .Because code refer clearcase path

Comment: @Refinath if you make a symlink which mimics the ClearCase path (and reference your checked out repo), then yes, it does work.

Comment: And what is the approach creating symbolic link for the directory ? or for the entire file.? if the project contains more than 1000 files we have to create that much symlinks right ?

Comment: @Refinath No. One symlink only (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) to the root folder of your repo.

Comment: One more doubt . I f I use symlink , I f have check out two instances from git . Then there will occur a  conflict. right? Because both project folder have symlink /vobs. So if I use at a time one person can can one instance . Am I correct ? Is there any way to handle multiple instances ?

Comment: @Refinath yes: since you won't be using both *at the same time*, each repo can have its own build script which will handle/change the symlink to point to its own root folder. But if you were to use both at the same time, then you would need to checkout those repo in docker container, in order to benefit from filesystem isolation.

Comment: @Haji Is there anything else missing to this answer?

Comment: Not checked yet . busy with other works. Will check soon