# Is Continuous Integration possible with ClearCase?

Tags: version-control, jenkins, continuous-integration, clearcase, atomic

We are running nightly builds on a Jenkins server and we use ClearCase as a Source Control Management.

Since ClearCase is **file-centric**, files checkin operate one by one. Contrary to SVN or Git (which are repository-centric), modifications by developers are not committed [atomically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_transaction).

This is not problematic during the night, because developers are not active anymore and the ClearCase server has a lock at 1 AM.

But here is an example of what could be a cause of concern when developers are active by day (let's say that builds run every half an hour):

```
10:55 AM - Developer1 checks in element1
10:55 AM - Developer1 checks in element2
10:56 AM - Developer1 checks in element3
11:00 AM - ### Jenkins runs BUILD #1 ### <-- succeeds
11:29 AM - Developer2 checks in element1
11:29 AM - Developer2 checks in element2
11:30 AM - ### Jenkins runs BUILD #2 ### <-- fails (element3 is missing)
11:29 AM - Developer2 checks in element3
```

Thus, are **Release Builds** (aka "ASAP Builds" or literally "Continuous Integration") worth considering with ClearCase or are we condemned to content ourselves with nightly builds forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using UCM, you can also consider the [ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin), and only trigger a build on demand, when a baseline is created.

That way:

- the developer controls when a continuous build is appropriate, but adding a baseline (and cleaning old ones if needed).
- Jenkins can promote baselines, making it easier to trace what build has succeeded or failed.

You can even provide a script for the developer to use for:

- check-in all the current checked-out file
- set a baseline automatically

That would help the user trigger that continuous integration, since he/she can decide when the current code base is stable enough to be committed (and tested).

---

You can still use that idea with base ClearCase: simply make sure to put a shifting label on *all* the file (shifting means: if a file has a previous version with that label, the label would be moved to the LATEST version just checked-in by the developer).

Your Jenkins CC view would be configured to display all files with that label, which means if said label moves to a new version, the `cleartool lshistory` done by Jenkins will change, and a build will be triggered. 
(Note: you [cannot yet do it for a pattern of label](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13021))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have point it out; we don't use UCM but only base ClearCase. What could be an answer without the use of UCM, then?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert I have edited my answer: the idea is to trigger the build based on a label, not just on a new checked-in file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clearcase plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin It looks a bit complex to implement but has recent updates.

On the other hand, you could bridge to git/svn [How to bridge git to ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342131/how-to-bridge-git-to-clearcase)

Comment: In fact, we are already using this plugin. I was wondering if this plugin was only useful at night and become useless at day?