# How do I integrate Beyond Compare with ClearCase?

Tags: merge, diff, clearcase, beyondcompare

I would like to integrate Beyond Compare with ClearCase so that I can use it for diffing and merging files, instead of the awful tools provided by ClearCase.

Does anyone have instructions for performing this integration?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase

Comment: i would suggest you mark @vonc answer as correct.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437), just modify the **map file** located in:

```
# up to ClearCase 7.0
c:\program files\rational\ClearCase\lib\mgrs
```

or

```
# ClearCase 7.1 and more
c:\program files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs
```

> Each map line has 3 parts: the CC filetype, the CC action, and the application.
>
> In your case, find the section in the map file for **`text_file_delta`** file types.
>   There you will find lines for CC actions `compare`, `xcompare`, `merge`, and `xmerge`.

[Use BeyondCompare](http://tutorial.downloadatoz.com/use-beyond-compare-with-clearcase.html):

```
text_file_delta xcompare C:\Progra~1\Beyond~1\bc2.exe
```

Beyond Compare 3 support all CC actions:

```
text_file_delta compare C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
text_file_delta xcompare C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
text_file_delta merge C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
text_file_delta xmerge C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
```

Note: For Beyond Compare 2, [this page](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?c=kb_vcs.php) clearly mentions

> To use Beyond Compare 2, only change the `xcompare` line of the map file.
>   Overriding `compare`, `merge`, and `xmerge` is not supported.
>   A helper that improves BC2's support is [available here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/ClearDiffBC.zip).

---

Note that what precedes is for ClearCase only, not CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client)

[This technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256807#ccrc) illustrates how to change the XML diff/Merge tool for CCRC (**KDiff3 but you can adapt it to BeyondCompare**):

> Change directories to the `CCRC installation location > plugins > com.ibm.rational.clearcase.compare_merge.<os>_<ccrc ver>`,
>   Where `<os>` is the name of the operating system bits used and `<ccrc ver>` is the latest version of the CCRC update applied on the client.
>
> On Windows
>
> - CCRC 7.1  Default: `C:\Program Files\IBM\IMShared\plugins`
> - CCRC 7.0 Default: `C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\ClearCase\CCRC\plugins\`
>
> Example:

```
com.ibm.rational.clearcase.compare_merge.win32x86_7.0.1.CU02
```

> - Copy the KDiff3 executable from its installation path to the `com.ibm.rational.clearcase.compare_merge.<os>_<ccrc ver>` directory
> - Rename the `ccrc_xmldiffmrg.exe` to `ccrc_xmldiffmrg_orig.exe`
> - Rename `KDiff3.exe` to `ccrc_xmldiffmrg.exe`
> - Close and reopen CCRC

#### CCRC Issue:

> When updating CCRC, the plug-in directory `com.ibm.rational.clearcase.compare_merge.<os>_<ccrc ver>` **will change**.
>   **The steps above will need to be run again in the new plug-in directory**.
>
> Note: You can control when the updates occur by preventing CCRC from looking for updates automatically.
>   Click `Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Automatic Updates` and disable automatic updates.

[image: disable automatic updates on CCRC]

Comment: Hi, I performed the steps above, but my CCRC still uses the default diffMerge.  This didn't work for me.  Any other advise?

Comment: @falconK that answer is for ClearCase only, not CCRC.

Comment: Clarification:  I only use CCRC, but just tried the native CC explorer, executed a compare with predecesor operation, and beyondCompare showed up.  So the steps above work ONLY for the Native ClearCase client, not for the Remote Client.  Any ideas for CCRC users??

Comment: @falconK for CCRC, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256807#ccrc (for KDiff3, but you can adapt it to other diff tool)

Comment: If you're using Notepad++ the regex  SEARCH: ((text_file_delta|_html|_xml|html2|xml2)[ \t]+(compare|xcompare|merge|xmerge)[ \t]+).* Replace: \1C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 3\\BCompare.exe does em all in one shot for regular clearcase

Comment: I tried changing `binary_delta` in the map file to Beyond compare but when diffing a png file it still said that binary diff is not supported. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc try changing it for `whole_copy`, not `binary_delta`.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Beyond Compare is [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), which integrates very nicely with clearcase. Just tick off for clearcase integration when installing, and you're done.

[image]

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with integrating Beyond Compare with ClearCase.

Comment: I didn't realize there were other diff tools that integrated with CC (not that I looked) until I saw this post, I think it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just to piggy back on Von's answer if you're lazy like me.

if you can search and replace with regex (like notepad++)

```
Find What:((text_file_delta|_html|_xml|html2|xml2)[ \t]+(compare|xcompare|merge|xmerge)[ \t]+).* 

Replace with: \1C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 3\\BCompare.exe
```

does all of the lines VonC mentioned for regular clearcase.

(assuming you have beyond compare installed at the above location, otherwise point to your path).

I also found it interesting, I put "'s around the path (due to the spaces) and it didn't work, removing them solved that problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the 'official' way on the BC support page:

[Ofiicial Tip by Scooter](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs)

> ```
> 1. Locate the plugins folder, which will contain a specific version named subfolder.  Examples:
>     C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\ClearCase701\CCRC\plugins\com.ibm.rational.clearcase.compare_merge.win32.x86_7.0.1.D061004
>     C:\Program Files\IBM\IMShared\plugins\com.ibm.rational.clearcase.compare_merge.win32.x86_7.1.1.v201007070751
>     Note that the version number in path is subject to change.
> 2. Copy "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\bcomp.exe" into the folder.
> 3. Move ccrc_cleardiff.exe, ccrc_cleardiffmrg.exe, ccrc_worddiffmrg.exe and ccrc_xmldiffmrg.exe to a backup folder.
> 4. Make 4 copies of bcomp.exe and rename them to ccrc_cleardiff.exe, ccrc_cleardiffmrg.exe, ccrc_worddiffmrg.exe and ccrc_xmldiffmrg.exe.
> 5. Change "CCRC Integrated (UTF-8)" to "ClearCase External" under Preferences | CCRC | Integration | Compare_Merge.
> ```

BUT there's something else you should do.
When setting the merge tool, you should override the comparison to the original 'CCRC Integrated', like so:

[image: Override directory comparison]

BC does not yet handle Clear Case Directory Comparison.

Comment: I didn't know BC couldn't handle CC directory comparison. +1