# Beyond compare integration with Clearcase failed

Tags: version-control, clearcase, beyondcompare

I tried to integrate Beyond Compare 3 with clearcase. But it failed and simply opening up the defauly compare application coming with clearcase.

Here is the following data I had given in 
**`C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs\map`** file. (I'm using clearcase SDLC).
I also tried with WinMerge but it also has failed. What could be the reason?

```
text_file_delta     compare             C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
text_file_delta     xcompare            C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
text_file_delta     merge               C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
text_file_delta     xmerge              C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Me too, modifying the map file did not make any difference.

However, I'm using Rational ClearCase Explorer 7.0 for Rhapsody and DiffMerge knows how to deal with the Rhapsody files.

If this is your case, by default, the diff tool used for text files is tkdiff but you may modify the preferences (located under View menu) in DiffMerge in order to use BC instead.

So do "Find Checkouts" in CC Explorer and do a comparison on a file (typically a .cls file) with its previous version. DiffMerge opens. Go in View -> Preferences -> TextDiffMerge and modify these lines:

```
BaseAwareDiffInvocation: "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe" $source1 $source2 $sourceBase
BaseAwareDiffMergeInvocation: $BaseAwareDiffInvocation $output
DiffInvocation: "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe" /readonly $source1 $source2
DiffMergeInvocation: "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe" $source1 $source2 /mergeoutput=$output
```

Click Ok. Then look for a modified method in the class and start a "Diff Text" on the ItsBody line. You should be in business!

Answer (score 0):

This looks good, as detailed in "[How do I integrate Beyond Compare with ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297834/how-do-i-integrate-beyond-compare-with-clearcase/3298184#3298184)".

So one reason why it could still fail is that the type manager of the file you are trying to diff is not "text_file_delta".
You can check that by selected "element properties" on the contextual menu of the file in the ClearCase explorer.

Comment: I checked some files and it display type as "text_file" in element properties.

Comment: @sarat: does the fact that if "fails" open up some kind of error message before displaying the default xdiff GUI?