# Using WinMerge as ClearCase diff viewer for xml files

Tags: clearcase, winmerge

I just installed WinMerge and checked its "Integrate with ClearCase" option. ClearCase now runs Winmerge when i execute "compare with previous version" on my java source files. However, when I run the same command on an xml file, it opens xml diff merge. How can I get it to open Winmerge instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See for instance "[How do I integrate Beyond Compare with ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297834/how-do-i-integrate-beyond-compare-with-clearcase/3298184#3298184)"

You need to modify

```
# up to ClearCase 7.0
c:\program files\rational\ClearCase\lib\mgrs
```

or

```
# ClearCase 7.1 and more
c:\program files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs
```

See the [technote swg21256807](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256807) for detail on Changing the XML Diff/Merge Type Manager.

> For any type manager that uses **`xmldiffmrg`**, replace the `xmldiffmrg` executable with your own.

Example (not for your tool, but you get the idea):

```
_xml2       compare          ..\..\..\..\KDiff3\KDiff3.exe
_xml2       xcompare         ..\..\..\..\KDiff3\KDiff3.exe
_xml2       merge            ..\..\..\..\KDiff3\KDiff3.exe
_xml2       xmerge           ..\..\..\..\KDiff3\KDiff3.exe
```

> Note: The `mapfile` uses a relative path from its current location to find the executable.
>   In this example, `KDiff3` was installed to the default directory on Windows (`C:\Program Files\KDiff3`) thus the relative path defined in the map file reflects as such.