# Not able to deliver ucm files

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have clearcase ucm with one int and two dev streams A and B. Two developers are working on two dev streams and modifying the same file.

A delivers to int and its code is built. The next time when I try to deliver B, it shows a conflict and while resolving the conflict, I can only select either the A change or B change.

I want to have both since A is already delivered and B I am delivering now. How should I resolve? Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Please don't confuse "too broad" with "I don't have any clue what ClearCase is". For any ClearCase/ClearCase UCM specialist (namely: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/topusers), this is specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the expected behavior?

It depends on which tool you are using to resolve the conflict. If it is a three-way merge tool, it should allows you to select both (source and destination of the merge), compared to a common ancestor.

This is what is described in "[Using tools to compare and merge files and directories](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccteam_diffmerge.htm)"

> For merges that require you to resolve a conflict, the Rational ClearTeam Explorer includes tools that provide type-specific compare and merge capabilities

But nothing stops you to plug an external tool ([BeyondCompare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298184/6309), [`kdiff3`, WinMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127337/6309)...)

Comment: Its a three way merge tool from clearcase default. But unfortunately for any unresolved difference, i can only choose one out of 3 options(1,2,3) .

Comment: @user2636464 What version of ClearCase are you using? On which OS?

Comment: its version 8 on windows 7. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: @user2636464 not necessarily: it depends on the version tree which would show (when done on the destination checked-out version) the source of the merge and the common ancestor: that would help illustrate why the merge only takes into account A or B.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will check on this again with clearteam explorer as well.

Comment: Assuming a text file, you can select both the from and to contributors to go into the output. However, if it's an unresolved change that prevented an "automatic" merge, it means that both developers changed the same section of code, and it may be incumbent upon the second developer to make sure that they account for both sets of changes. Not having the merge window in front of me, I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @BrianCowan Exactly it is  a text file and an unresolved change and both developers changed the same section of code. However since changes from first developer already was delivered to integration, second developer expected that when delivering his changed , both the changes will go into the output.

Comment: @user2636464 If 2 developers edited the same line of code, then this is a completely valid merge conflict regardless of the tool. In which case the 2 developers need to get together and figure out a way to integrate their changes in a way where both work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Kdiff3 with CC integration and rerun the "merge" so it will use Kdiff3

Comment: It would depend on the nature of the changes. If 2 developers made changes to the same line of text, it may still require assistance. But a tool that handles intra-line changes (kdiff3 may, winmerge and BeyondCompare do) may be able to integrate the changes for you. Whether that's a good thing depends on the nature of the changes...