# ClearCase quick diff eclipse

Tags: eclipse, diff, clearcase

Is possible enabled quick diff for Clearcase in Eclipse?

I use plugins

```
Rational ClearCase Remote Client for Eclipse Import 7.1.0.v201001271035--08422A2_242663 com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccimport.feature.feature.group
```

and

```
Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter  7.6.0.v201105111445 com.rational.clearcase.feature.group
```

In

Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Quick Diff -> Use this reference source

isn't some ClearCase choice.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Quick Diff"](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-local-history-quick) itself isn't available in Eclipse SCM adapter:

[image: quick diff]

That leaves you with the possibility to define *external* diff tools and make them open when you do a "Compare with previous" from Eclipse.
See for instance:

- "[How do I integrate Beyond Compare with ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297834/how-do-i-integrate-beyond-compare-with-clearcase/3298184#3298184)", or
- "[Any way to use a custom diff tool with cleartool/clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437)"

---

Note: with ClearCase 8.0, the RCE (Rational ClearTeam Explorer) is preferred to the Eclipse SCM Adapter, both for CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) and full ClearCase usage.
See "[About Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter in Rational ClearCase version 8.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21589163)".
And "[Using the Rational ClearTeam Explorer for Eclipse](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccrc_eclipse.htm)" doesn't show any "quick diff" feature either.

Answer (score 0):

Quick diff is not supported by ClearCase plugin for Eclipse.