# Use bcompare with clearcase

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm using clearcare as command line. I want to compare a checked out file with predecessor. I use the command :

- `ct diff -graphical -predecessor $file`

But the diff is done with xcompare. Is there a way to use bcompare instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check first if "[How do I integrate Beyond Compare with ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298184/6309)" that I wrote in 2010 can help.

Beyond Compare itself has an [official page](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs), but it might not work in an Unix environment.

Comment: Your instructions are still valid as the type manager interface hasn't changed at all. If the Beyond Compare Unix cli options have changed, a wrapper script may be needed.