# Use bcompare to see difference with previous version

Tags: diff, clearcase

I actually use clearcase file browser to see version tree for a specific file. I can select the version for a baseline and do diff with predecessor.

But I want to do that with bcompare in commandline.

I have myFile.c and the baseline Version_XX_YY_ZZ, how can I do to compare with the previous version with bcompare ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash

BASELINE="Version_XX_YY_ZZ"
FILE="myFile.c"

cleartool lsvtree "$FILE" | grep "$BASELINE" > ~/tmp.txt

# tmp.txt must contain only 1 line

# get file name for $BASELINE
BaseFile=$(cat ~/tmp.txt | cut -d' ' -f1)
# get predecessor file short name
PredFile=$(cleartool descr -pred -short "$BaseFile" | cut -d$'\n' -f1)

# Start compare
bcompare "$FILE"@@"$PredFile" "$BaseFile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you can [integrate Beyond Compare with ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298184/6309) as I documented before (it might have changed since 2010)

The [official documentation is here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) and does edit the `C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs` file.

Comment: I've tried to integrate beyond compare but my company doesn't allow to modify clearcase tools