# Why Won't Clearcase Explorer Diff My XML Files?

Tags: xml, clearcase

I have a situation in Clearcase where I right click to find checkouts and then right click any xml.  When I choose "Compare with previous versions", it just pops up with an "XML Diff Merge - Comparing" window that stays minimized in my taskbar.

Strangely enough, it doesn't have this problem with Java files, just the XML ones. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML files are managed by a different [type manager](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/type_manager.htm).
That explains the difference between a text file (`.java`)  and an xml one.

Depending on the size,  structure or encoding, the ClearCase xml diff tool can hang (or crash)

As detailed in "[Any way to use a custom diff tool with cleartool/clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437)", the diff tool for xml file ([`xmldiffmrg`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/xmldiffmrg.htm)) is declared (and [can be changed in](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256807)) "`C:\program files\rational\ClearCase\lib\mgrs\map`"

```
text_file_delta   compare          ..\..\bin\cleardiff.exe
text_file_delta   xcompare         ..\..\bin\cleardiffmrg.exe
_xml2             compare          ..\..\bin\xmldiff.exe
_xml2             xcompare         ..\..\bin\xmldiffmrg.exe
```

In your case, I suspect the diff works, the windows open, *but* outside of the screen:

[image: cleardiffmrg]

Check your registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\`: you could find a section dedicated to cleardiff, with screen coordinates that you would then be able to reset.

---

More simply, the [OP Phil Cote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547350/phil-cote) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747393/why-wont-clearcase-explorer-diff-my-xml-files/12747786#comment18036710_12747786):

> You were right that this was showing up outside the window.
>   The regedit turned out to be unnecessary.
>   **I did a right-click "move" which made cross arrows appear. Then I hit an arrow key and the window just popped up right at my mouse cursor**.
>   I'm guessing it's one of those silly beginner windows tricks I had never known about til now.

You can see that process detailed in "[Windows 7 rightclick menu from toolbar like ALT-SPACE?](https://superuser.com/questions/360169/windows-7-rightclick-menu-from-toolbar-like-alt-space)"

Comment: You were right that this was showing up outside the window.  The regedit turned out to be unnecessary.  I did a right-click "move" which made cross arrows appear.  Then I hit an arrow key and the window just popped up right at my mouse cursor.  I'm guessing it's one of those silly beginner windows tricks I had never known about til now.

Comment: @PhilCote Excellent. I have added your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 11):

We have had the same problem.
How to fix it:
Open `regedit.exe` and delete the whole branch
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\XML Diff Merge`.

Restart `ClearCase Explorer`.

The previosly deleted regestry `key/branch` will be re-create with default values.

Then the merge window is visible again.

Comment: Great, I needed this!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that I had to Shift-Rightclick the "XML Diff" task in the taskbar in order to Move/Maximize the window.  Rightclicking alone did not provide these options.