# How can I set the graphical diff tool for ClearCase on Linux, as non-root?

Tags: user-interface, diff, clearcase, cleartool

I want to replace the GUI tool ClearCase brings up when I use `cleartool diff`. I've read:

[Any way to use a custom diff tool with cleartool/clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase)

but the answers there are either about Windows, or they show me shell scripts which I don't know how to  use. Or there are kludges like [this one](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11216/Custom-diff-tool-for-clearcase-object?fromPage=1).

On the other hand, I do know that ClearCase uses a symlink, e.g. `/opt/rational/clearcase/lib/mgrs/directory/xcompare`, for the graphical diff'ing. Except that this symlink is owned by root, and I'm not root. Also, I don't want to replace *everybody*'s diff tool, just mine.

So, what can I do to have ClearCase use the tool I want it to?

Note: I'm using GNU/Linux (Devuan 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I don't want to replace everybody's diff tool, just mine

That points out to a Unix client, where you want to open a Unix diff tool different from `xcompare` (without using the [command-line tool `cleardiff`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/cleardiff.htm) or [`cleartool diff`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm)).

You would still need to [modify the `ccase-home-dir/lib/mgrs/manager-name`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/type_manager.htm) , with `ccase-home-dir` refering to both the Rational ClearCase installation directory).

The goal is to replace the executable of the line `text_file_delta   xcompare         ../../bin/cleardiffmrg` by the graphical tool of your choice ([kdiff3 for instance](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/))

So that would still affect all users of the ClearCase client on that machine (as opposed to Windows, where you are generally the only user).

Comment: So, there are no user-specific overrides for these links?

Comment: @einpoklum Not to my knowledge.