# Config spec in rational clearcase

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I am so much new to these clear case tool.I am learning because i have a project to work on.
i just learned the default config spec is

```
element *CHECKEDOUT
element */main/LATEST
```

So the new version is created in the `main` branch after the previous version.
But I have been trying these, and I just changed my config spec to these

```
element *CHECKEDOUT
element */main/2
```

After those settings, when I click the file it says "`file not found`": I cannot check in or check out.
And then I changed to default config spec its working again.

Whats wrong?
Also tell me these How can I go to a `version 4` to create a branch over there if my latest version is 6 in `main` ?

Answer (score 2):

By making a selection rule:

```
 element */main/2
```

You instruct ClearCase to only show you "version 2" of... Everything:

```
 /my/path/to/a/File
```

So if any of the parent directory of '`aFile`' has no "version 2' yet, you won't be able to access `aFile`.

You should always keep a '`/main/LATEST`' selection rule at the *end* of your config spec in order, if any of the previous rules don't work, to *fall back* to that one universal rule (universal because any element has at least its `version 0` stored in the '`main`' branch, unless '`main`' has been renamed, which is very bad)

For instance:

```
 element * CHECKEDOUT
 element * /main/2
 element * /main/LATEST
```

will work, and will show you `version 2` of everything if they have one, or the LATEST version if they don't.

When you want to create a branch from a certain point, it is best to not rely on a version number (because what you call 'version 4' is only valid for your file, not for your directory).
Don't forget that files and directory are versioned in a element-basis: you version a file, then a directory, then another file...: it is file-centric, not repository-centric like other VCS (SVN, Git, Mercurial, ...) with an atomic commit and *one* revision number for the all repo: here you have *individual* version number for each element (file or directory).
See "[What are the basic ClearCase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771)" for more

It is best to have set a label first, in order to branch from there.

But if you don't have a label, my advice would be to:

- determine a point in time where your code where at the state you want it to be for your branch
- make a [time-based selection rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634509/clearcase-loading-older-version-of-a-specific-directory)
- complete that selection rule with a mkbranch directive
- don't forget the new files you will add on that branch (that's the '`/main/0`' rule)

So:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../myBranch/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -time dd-Month-yyyy -mkbranch myBranch
element * /main/0 -mkbranch myBranch
element * /main/LATEST
```

will create a new branch '`myBranch`' for any element created at most at the dd-Month-yyy date.

Comment: but we dont remember the time and date mostly . we only remember the versions exactly

Comment: vonC would u please give me some links or documents to study these tool please its really an urgent and important thing i need to learn

Comment: i need to know and learn the config spec rules and syntax how to write the code

Comment: @cody: my point is: the version for one element (one file) isn't useful. Each directory and file has its own history, its own version tree. To make a branch from one file, you need to know what exact version of the other elements (particularly the parent directories) you want to select. And they won't always have the same 'version number'. See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_version_tree.htm

Comment: @cody: see also http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bcfg_hwcfgwrk.htm