# Config spec for specific file

Tags: version-control, clearcase

How would you see a specific file version in the ClearCase ?

How to set the right config spec for that specific file?

Comment: Note: you can write to team@stackoverflow.com and ask to associate you several cody account and your zacc account together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a specific selection rule for a specific file, but that won't help you actually *accessing* it.

For instance:

```
element /path/to/my/File /main/4
```

would select the version 4 of branch `main` only for `/path/to/my/File`.
But considering that the parent directories '`path`', '`to`', and '`my`' have they own version (which isn't likely to be '4'), they won't be selected *at all* by that single rule.

(Don't forget that directories are versioned when their content changes: version 4 would mean their content have changed 4 times, in other words, that files or subdirectories have been added or removed 4 times)

To be sure to select the right version for a file, *while being able to access it*, you need 2 rules in the right order (as explained in "[How to create a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580597/how-to-create-a-branch/6581282#6581282)"):

```
 element /path/to/my/File /main/4
 element * /main/LATEST
```

That way, you would see the right version in your (snapshot or dynamic) ClearCase view for that file.
But that wouldn't allow to checkout it (no `-mkbranch` directive there).