# What does these below code mean?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element  /test_ari/karthik/...  ... /karthik_omna/LATEST
element  /test_ari/karthik/...  /main/2  -mkbranch karthik_omna
element *  /main/LATEST
```

I have written the above code and it worked so right.I am so happy for that.But i want to clear somethings from u guys. What does that 3 dots mean in this syntax

```
 /test_ari/karthik/...
```

and the other 3 dots means

```
 ... /karthik_omna/LATEST
```

And last question but it got great importance. Why should we always use `*  CHECKEDOUT` in the beginning? what happens if we dont use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/test_ari/karthik/...
```

It means that the selection rule which follows (i.e `.../karthik_omna/LATEST`) will apply to the `karthik` directory, and to all the subdirectories and files, recursively.
If the selection path had been `/test_ari/karthik/*` (star instead of three dots), the selection rule would have applied to the subdirectories and files, but *not* to the `karthik` directory itself

---

```
.../karthik_omna/LATEST
```

This is a selection rule instructing ClearCase to select the LATEST version of the branch `karthik_omna`, without worrying on top of what other branch `karthik_omna` has been created.
If the selection rule had been (for example) `/main/karthik_omna/LATEST`, it would have selected the `LATEST` version of that branch *only if* said branch was created on top of '`main`'.
Contrary to the previous '`...`', there is no '`*`' for a selection rule.
(`*/karthik_omna/LATEST` doesn't exist)

---

As I explained in "[How to create a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580597/how-to-create-a-branch/6581282#6581282)", selection rules are read in order and the first one that fits make ClearCase apply it (and ignore the others) for a particular file or directory.

This is why you will always find:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
```

as the first rule, because when you notify ClearCase of your intention to modify that file, it (the file) acquires a special version called `CHECKEDOUT` which needs to be selected in order for you to be able to modify and then check-in that file.
If that rule was too far down below, ClearCase might select another version, and you wouldn't be able to check-in anything since that file would not be considered checked-out in your view.

Comment: thank you von c you made me clear completely but did not understand these syntax /test_ari/karthik/* u mean it does not apply to the files of karthik directory but to the files of its sub directories right? /test_ari/karthik... and these applies to the files of karthik directory too right?

Comment: @cody: yes, that is correct. With a '*', the directory alone `karthik` will have to be selected by some other rules below.