# Label ClearCase Content As Seen On A Given Date (without changing the config specs)

Tags: command-line, find, clearcase

I need to label the contents of a view as seen at specific dates, and the only way I know of doing it is by using the **-time version selector** in the config specs. I set the time to the date I want, and then I apply the label on the view. Simple.

However, I was hoping if there is a way to do it pro-grammatically *without changing the config specs*. I was hoping that I could use the `cleartool find` in combination with `-exec` and `mklabel`. However, if I do this:

```
cleartool find . -cview -version "! created_since(some-date)"
```

It only pulls what was created before that date *on the view*, not necessarily what should be seen in the view if we were using the **`-time` selector**.

And if I use `cleartool find` with a `-branch` selector

```
cleartool find . -cview -version "! created_since(some-branch)"
```

it only selects that which was created before that date, on that branch only. It will not show what is also seen in the view on other branches via the config specs rules.

So, am I using `cleartool find` wrong? Or is it just impossible?

Is there a way, from the command line, to direct `cleartool find` to find exactly and precisely the elements that

1. would be seen by the active config rules
2. in a given directory
3. regardless of the branch or branches involved,
4. ***AS IF*** there was a -time directive in them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the [query language](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm) isn't rich enough to include what the [config spec](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm) time rule does.
A [time-based selection rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634509/clearcase-loading-older-version-of-a-specific-directory) is the best option.

What I generally do, in order to use the `-time` programmatically (since the find wouldn't work) is to:

- use a dedicated dynamic view (quicker to update than a snapshot view)
- write in a file the config spec I need
- `cleartool setcs -tag myView myFile # update the config spec of the dynamic view`
  (See [`setcs` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm))
- use the result of the updated content of the dynamic view.

Comment: I didn't think of using a dedicated dynamic view and changing its c-specs on the fly. That'll certainly works for me. Thanks!