# How to apply baseline for previous version?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

I have done a mistake by not applying baseline for one of my release.

Now some more changes were done in the integration stream. Is it possible to apply baseline for particular past day's changes.

We are using Clearcase UCM.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it... but not easily on the same branch.

- You can create a non-UCM view with the files at the versions referenced by your earlier date (see "[Label ClearCase Content As Seen On A Given Date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745217/label-clearcase-content-as-seen-on-a-given-date-without-changing-the-config-spe/8745812#8745812)")
- Then you can create and apply a label on all the versions visible in that non-UCM view
- Then [create a baseline by **importing the label**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/t_u_prj_bl_mk_lbl.htm)

However that will create a baseline on a separate branch, and not on the current stream.
that is not good, as you won't be able to compare that new imported baseline with all your other baselines (because they won't have any common ancestor).

The only way to easily create your baseline *on your Stream* (and benefit from the comparison with previous baselines) is to use your non-UCM view in order to `clearfsimport -rmname` the content of that view to your current view, importing all the versions (in your current UCM view) to the right content (ie the content selected by your date in your non-UCM view).
See "[Best way to roll back to previous versions without baseline in CC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232540/best-way-to-roll-back-to-previous-versions-without-baseline-in-cc/9233503#9233503)" (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416875/creating-a-new-subdirectory-structure-in-clearcase/418196#418196) for more on `clearfsimport`).
Do it in a specific activity dedicated to record all the modifications done by that import.

Then you put your baseline.

Finally, cancel that activity, using the cset.pl script: See "[Clearcase: how to rollback all changes on specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039121/clearcase-how-to-rollback-all-changes-on-specific-branch/6039686#6039686)".
You should get back all the versions you had before making that import.

The drawback is that your history for a given file will reflect a curious 'setback' in the list of versions on the branch of your Stream.

Comment: Note: the second solution supposes you didn't create any new baseline since the date when you forget to put one.