# How do you get all files of a VOB as of a given date in a clearcase vob?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

I have a fairly large codebase with several directories and files and I would like to check out a view or have a view as of a given date (Septermber 12th). I am manually checking file histories and doing `ct get -to someOtherDir/FileName FilenName@@/main/##` and this is extremely painful. I wonder if there is a way to do a checkout and load everything as of a particular day at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a separate dynamic view, with a config spec including a **time-based selection rule** (or time rule for short, see [`cleartool man config_spec`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm)).

See as an example "[ClearCase : Loading Older Version of a specific Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634509/clearcase-loading-older-version-of-a-specific-directory/635282#635282)".

Since you want to checkout files, you need to complete your selection rule by a `mkbranch` directive.

```
element * .../aBranch/LATEST
element /aVob/myComponent/mySubDirectory/... .../aParentBranch/LATEST -time dd-Month-yyyy -mkbranch aBranch
element * /main/LATEST
```

If those elements were all created on '`aParentBranch`', they will be selected at the right date, and branched into a new branch '`aBranch`' when checked out.

If those elements were all on `/main`, you can switch the last two selection rules into:

```
element * /main/LATEST -time dd-Month-yyyy -mkbranch aBranch
```

From the [man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm):

```
-time date-time
```

> Modifies the meaning of the special version label `LATEST`:
>   the rule selects from a branch the last version that was created *before* a particular time.

Comment: This -time syntax works, thanks this must have saved me a couple hours at least!