# time rule in perforce

Tags: perforce, clearcase

I want to restrict files from main to be older than 04 Jan 2013. In `clearcase` I can accomplish this using `time` command:

```
time 04-Jan-2013.01:00:00
element * /main/LATEST
```

I would like to know how to do this in `perforce`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [perforce sync page](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/manuals/p4web/help/sync.html) mentions that you can use a date:

```
Label or Date
```

> Sync to a specific symbolic revision revision (either a label or date). Enter the label or date in the space provided.

That seems more appropriate that a [`p4 rollback`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Working_with_changelists.html), which applies changelist per changelist.

From [`p4 sync`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/sync.html):

```
p4 sync @2011/06/24
```

> Bring the workspace into sync with the depot as of midnight, June 24, 2011. (That is, include all changes made during June 23.)

Comment: Note to self: example of time-based config spec in ClearCase: http://stackoverflow.com/a/635282/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10703661/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12827358/6309

Comment: Using the sync syntax, you can build some tooling that automatically syncs to the right timestamp.  That can a user-invoked tool or done automatically in the Perforce Broker.