# clearcase command to backup predecessor version of a file?

Tags: clearcase

what is the clearcase command to backup predecessor version of a file ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try **[cleartool get](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm)** to copy any old version of a file into a temporary file.

```
cleartool get –to C:\build\foo.c.temp \dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2
```

More generally, the question "[In ClearCase, how can I view old version of a file in a static view, from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-com)" will detail all the possibilities to access the content of previous versions of a given file.