# ClearCase: Is it possible to version control the config spec itself?

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

I have complicated Config Spec, which changes quite often.
Is it possible to version control the config spec itself?

e.g.,
suppose the current config spec is:
    element * CHECKEDOUT

```
element /vobs/a/b/c.v  /main/34
element /vobs/a/d/e.v  /main/20
element /vobs/f/g.f LABEL_0.592
element /vobs/... LABEL_0.596
```

While the previous config spec was:
    element * CHECKEDOUT

```
element /vobs/h/i/j.v  /main/31
element /vobs/... LABEL_0.595
```

I'd like to be able to "go back" to my previous config spec, without having to keep it in comments inside the config spec, or copy-paste it every time to seperate file, and have that file version controlled.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

You could version the config spec itself (obtained with [`cleartool catcs -tag YourViewTag > aConfigSpecFile`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_catcs.htm)) in its own branch (in order to not interfere with the regular versioning of the other files)

The idea is that you can set a config spec from a file at any time, with [`cleartool setcs`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm):

```
cleartool setcs -tag yourViewTag yourConfigSpecFile
```

To get a specific version of that config spec (since it is stored in its own branch), [you can use `cleartool get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381646/6309)

```
cleartool get –to yourConfigSpec yourConfigSpec@@\main\aBranch\x
```

Comment: That's what I've started to write here... you're the first one vonc :) 

@zvika - you can use cleartool catcs > filename to save the config spec

Comment: @Vonc - using `ct setcs -f` is a great solution. Googling added the info that I should also use `ct setcs -cur` to refresh the CS every time it's changed. Thanks!

Comment: @TamirGefen - Good to hear from you. If I'm not mistaken, we learnt together in Eli...

Comment: @Zvika I have edited the answer (there is no -f option), added links to the documentation and added how to get a specific version.