# Querying multiple versions of same file in Clearcase

Tags: find, clearcase, cleartool, versions

I would like to write a little batch script, which I would use to collect all of the comments of a file on a specific branch. For example, if I have an ABC.cpp file under the myBranch branch and it has already 3 versions, I would like to have the comments from version 1, 2 and 3.

I still couldn't get multiple versions of the same file. I am using the "find" command of cleartool. Maybe it is not possible in a simple cleartool find command, so let me know, if that's so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If is possible to list the version of a file, either with [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) (using the `-ver`), or with [`cleartool lshist`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm).

For a specific branch:

```
cleartool find . -name "ABC.cpp" -ver "{brtype(myBranch)}"
```

For each file, you can access its [content with `cleartool get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381646/6309).
See also "[In ClearCase, how can I view old version of a file in a static view, from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/177350/6309)"

```
cleartool find . -name "ABC.cpp" -ver "{brtype(myBranch)}" -exec
```