# How can I checkout a version of a file from another branch with Clearcase Remote Client

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm using the Clearcase Remote Client 7.1.2 (and I only have it available)

I have a file which has 2 branches, branch1 and branch2. branch1 is configured to be the default branch in config spec. I want to checkout a version of the file from branch2, but there is no such option in Version Tree Browser when I click any version of the file on branch2. I can only checkout the latest version on branch1.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a configuration that will allow me to checkout any version I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (CCRC web-)view is always defined to work at the latest version possible (LATEST) of a specific branch.

The [CLI associated with CCRC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) doesn't include '`get`' (presented in the **second part** of "[In ClearCase, how can I view old version of a file in a static view, from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-co/177350#177350)"

If your view isn't an UCM view, you could add a selection rule at the start of your config spec (See [CCRC edit config spec](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_edit_config.htm)):

```
element /vob/path/to/file .../branch2/x
```

with `x` a version number from `branch2`.
However, I don't remember if you have access to the actual config spec source with CCRC.

Comment: I see, thanks. So, from what I understand there is no easy way to do it, right? I will have to change my config spec every time I want to edit a version in a different branch (if I only have CCRC available).

Comment: @CagdasAltinkaya: yes. The question is, why do you need to change the version of a specific file for each and every branch you are in? Maybe is there a different solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the company I'm working for, many files have  more than one branches, I have to edit different ones for different requests. It's not a good practice, they should not be the way they are now, but I think using clearcase is an even bigger mistake. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @CagdasAltinkaya: Why have they more than one branch? Config file with one version per branch for each environment?

Comment: If only it was just config files... Many code files too have test/production/some_project branches.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create two views. One whose config spec selects versions in branch1 and another that selects versions in branch2. Use the appropriate view when checking out files.