# Wrong versions after moving a label (ClearCase)

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I baselined a stream this morning, but someone made changes to a couple files that they did not want included in the baseline.

I used the Version Tree to move the label from the newest version to the previous version.  (First, was this wrong?)

I then delivered that baseline to a stream in another project.  It works fine, and all the correct versions of the files came over.  However, now the file in view is version 22, and there is a version 23 that I am not able to see.  (I would like to see the newer version, even though I did not want that included in the baseline.)  Is there a way to make the view show the latest version of the file?

Note:  I tried making a new baseline, but ClearCase included version 22 in the baseline instead of version 23...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct course of action, when a Baseline doesn't reference the right content, is:

- to fix that content (delete as in "cleartool rmname" the files you don't want to see, checkout/checkin the files you want to fix, creating *new* versions)
- make a new baseline (you can take the same name, or 'title': ClearCase will generate a different baseline id based on that name: `BLNAME.xxxx`: see "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696598/what-is-the-difference-between-full-baseline-and-incremental-baseline-in-clearca/9696988#9696988)")

Moving a label is not a recommended solution (it is actually supposed to be impossible if that label is linked to a Baseline)

You then deliver that new baseline to any other Stream you want.
But if the source Stream has some new version, then you will need to make *another* baseline including said new version, and deliver that new baseline, in order for your destination project to see and reference it.

Comment: Is there any way to fix what I did?  The files were supposed to be in the baseline, but it was simply supposed to be the previous version instead of the new one that was checked in early.  Did I mess something up?

Comment: @Rubussu: it is best to restore a previous version by merging it to the current version, making a new one with the right content, and putting a new baseline. That is safer than trying to "fix" a previous hazardous manipulation.

Comment: Question relating to this topic:  If I want to test something with an older version, is there any problem with checking that version out using the version tree?  If I don't want to keep that version, I can just do an "undo checkout" and if I would like to keep it, I can just check it in and merge with the current version.  I don't see any problems with this, but I don't know if anything could go wrong in the future.

Comment: @Rubasu for a couple of files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-co/177350#177350 can help. For a all (older) baseline, simply make a child Stream, rebase it with said baseline, and do your test in a View attached to that child Stream.