# How to checkout the folder of a previous Revision Node in Clearcase using C#

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I have folder in ClearCase which has two Revision : `Rev.1` & `Rev.2`.

I want to checkout the Folder of revision 1 using C#. I am using ClearCasedll to checkout the file.
But its always checked out only the latest Revision Folder (meaning `Rev.2`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the **[full extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904)** of the revision you wish to checkout.
See also "[In ClearCase, how can I view old version of a file in a static view, from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-co/177350#177350)" for a practical example of selection of a previous version using extended pathname.

In your case, it might not be just about a file, but a folder content, so I would advise first to setup a (dynamic: it is quicker) view with the right config spec, selecting the right version, with a `-mkbranch` rule in order to prepare the checkout in its own branch (and then try your C# checkout).

But with UCM, you don't need to specify yourself the config spec if you have a Stream configured properly (ie configure to select the right version you want to checkout).

A checkout is done within the context of a view, and an UCM view is one attached to a stream: That means you will almways get the LATEST of the versions made on the branch named after that stream.

However, should you create a *substream*, based on the previous baseline (`Rev.1`), then you could checkout the right version in a new view attached to that substream.