# Copying an element from Clearcase with a particular label without using config specs

Tags: clearcase

How to copy an element or file from `Clearcase` with a particular `label`, without applying that `label` in `config specs`.

I don't want to change the config spec of my view, but I need to access an older version of one of my selected files, and I would like to do so directly from my existing view (again, without changing anything).
I know the version I want to restore (from instance version 2, even though I am selecting currently version 3 in my view).

[image]

What `cleartool` command would you use in order to access said old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-co/177350#177350), but only using a dynamic view (any existing dynamic view, not particular config spec required).
The article "[To open a version not currently in your view from a command prompt using a version-extended path](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_open_not_view.htm)" mentions that you can use a snapshot view too, but you would need for:

- the element to be already loaded (obviously not at the version you want)
- the old version to be *copied* into the view (as a private file): `cleartool get -to prog.old.c prog.c@@/main/r1_fix/1`

Note that the contextual menu of a version tree includes a "Send To" entry which would effectively do the cleartool get (i.e. the copy) for you.

[image]

---

But in a dynamic view, you don't need to copy anything, you can directly reference any old version:

```
cp foo.c@@/RLS4.3
cp include.h@@/main/bugfix/REL2
```

See also [version selector](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm):

> If a version label was defined to be one-per-element, **an additional link/file system object appears at the top level of an element's directory tree**.
>   For example, if `BL3` is a one-per-element label, these version-extended pathnames are both unambiguous references to the same version:

```
hello.c@@/BL3
hello.c@@/main/bugfix/patch2/BL3
```

> In effect, this feature allows you to reference a version without knowing its exact location in the version tree.

In a dynamic view, when you see hello.c in your view (and that can be *any* selected version, not the one you want with the label), you actually can do:

```
cd hello.c@@
dir
```

That will list all the unique labels for you to choose from.