# How to get particular Clearcase file of previous versions

Tags: shell, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool, clearcase-automation

Right now, I have a file called **`config_1_2_3.xml`** for current track of my product .
In previous track file was of version of **`config_1_2_2.xml`**.

I am getting the file of version 1_2_2 by doing the below manual steps:

- Open the version tree and get the particular file.
- Then choose the option "`Send to`".

But I want to write a script by help of which, I can get the previous file (1_2_2), and copy it to my local drive, which will reduce the manual effort.

What command would be involve when writing such a script?

Comment: I'll put an answer in a few hours, but try `cleartool get` as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381646/6309, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15184990/6309

Comment: Can we also.find out why you're not just using a view.to select the files for the previous release? If you're doing this to build a copy of the previous release, you might be building it with new.versions of files that are in common, meaning that your build isn't identical to said prior release. Using a full view would allow you to have a fully reproducible build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reproduce the "Send To" option of the version tree using the command **[`cleartool get`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm)**

```
cleartool get –to C:\build\foo.c.temp \dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2
```

Replace `\dev\hello_world\foo.c` by the file full path name, and `\main\2` by the branches and version number you have selected from the version tree.