# How does source control work with Python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, clearcase

I'm curious about what Python sees when using the subprocess command with respect to source control. I'm stuck using ClearCase, and whenever I start a terminal, I have my cshrc set up to start my view within ClearCase.

I know that when running a shell command via the subprocess module (subprocess.Popen), shell defaults to False. Without my view started on ClearCase, I shouldn't be able to see any files in my source control, but I know that I do. I'm able execute files within the source control.

How is that possible without a view started?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you could post the code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not accessing your view through /view (in Unix), where the [`cleartool setview` would trigger a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252436/python-and-clearcase-setview).
That isn't compatible with any system call done from a python script.

Running a shell would give you access to [extended path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176858/in-clearcase-how-can-i-view-old-version-of-a-file-in-a-static-view-from-the-co/177350#177350) (in dynamic view only).
You can also try and see what kind of result you would get with a library like **[pycleartool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycleartool)**.