# How to use CCRC to get prievous file version?

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I'm trying to use CCRC API in order to get pervious versions for a specific file and compare with the checkout file.

I know ClearCase can use get command. But how it works in CCRC API?

Does anybody have some example how to retrieve this version without changing the config spec?

Thanks,
Crispy

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rcleartool`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598728) has seen [new commands with CC8.0.0.3 and CC8.0.4](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728), but is still missing a '`get`' command except for the very latest ClearTeam version (8.0.1: see the [`rcleartool` list of commands](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rcleartool.htm)).
I said as much in "[How do I retreive previous or old version in CCRC 7.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16829143/6309)".

With CCRC 8 (aka ClearTeam Explorer) supporting dynamic view, you can try and use [version-extended path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309) (or [`rcleartool get`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm)), but if you are talking about CCRC, you are likely to be with a ClearCase 7.2.x instead of 8.x.

A separate dedicated web view, with a config spec you can change remains for now your safest as in "available right now") option.

---

> I'm writing code to compare my checkout file(some code is modified) with the latest version in clearcase. So I have to get the content of the previous version to compare with my checkout file.

That seems more a job for [`rcleartool diff -pred`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rcleartool.htm)

```
-pre/decessor
```

> Effectively converts the first `pname` argument into two names:
>
> - (1) the predecessor version of `pname` in the version tree;
> - (2) `pname` itself.
>
> If `pname` specifies a checked-out version, the predecessor is the version from which it was checked out.

Comment: Hi Vonc, Thanks for your reply. I'm talking about the latest CC8.x version. I still cannot find the get command in the rcleartool.jar. Besides, my view is web view not dynamic view.

Comment: CC8.x has `rcleartool get`. What does `rcleartool -ver` returns?

Comment: I'm writing code to compare my checkout file(some code is modified) with the latest version in clearcase. So I have to get the content of the previous version to compare with my checkout file. Do you have some other solutions to get that previous version easily without changing config spec?

Comment: Hi, @VonC Sadly, the rcleartool diff -pred is not supported in my CCRC version. Do you know which version support that command?

Comment: @crispyfries then it must be supported in 8.0.1

Comment: Thanks! I will check that version again.

Comment: @crispyfries I don't know of a separate download url for `rcleartool.jar` in 8.0.1: it is part of the ClearTeam Explorer V8.x product. Download urls are listed up to 8.0.0.2 in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found get command in clearcase 8.0.0.6.

Comment: @crispyfries sounds great. Does my post answers your question, then?