# Applying label in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am using CCRC. I have a text file with list of codes for which a label has to be applied.

Can some pleae suggest me a command to  label all the files mentioned in the text file.

Here I want to apply label only on selected files with in a folder and and not all the files with in the folder.

Is there any command to sort this out where we we can pass the a text file with code list as input and apply label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [rcleartool (the API for CCRC 7.x or ClearTeam 8.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269319/6309).

See if [`mklabel`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm) is available through rcleartool: its [man page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm) does mention "ClearCase Remote Client  rcleartool subcommand"

> ClearCase Remote Client: attach label to specified versions

```
mklabel [ -rep/lace ] [ -r/ecurse ] [ -fol/low ]
[ -silent ] [ -ver/sion version-selector ]
[ -c/omment comment | -cq/uery | -nc/omment ]
label-type-selector pname ...
```

You could use `mklabel` to apply a label type (already existing in your vob) to a specific file.
You can then loop on all the files to apply said label.

Comment: @user2707288 you are welcome, but I don't know for sure if `rcleartool mklabel` is available (especially since I don't know the exact version of the CCRC you are using).

Comment: I am using Version: 7.1.2 Build id: 7.1.2.07.00_2012B.D120613

Comment: @user2707288 then I don't know if `mklabel` is available or not. I saw it in the 8.x documentation.

Comment: Hi VonC, can you please suggest where and how I can find a complete tutorial for basic clearcase and CCRC.

Comment: @user2707288 the best sources, for rcleartool, is the one I mention in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18269319/6309. For ClearCase and CCRC in general, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21209312, the 7.1.2 help page (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp) remain the best sources