# Adapt SCM Implementation with Subversion to ClearCase

Tags: maven, svn, clearcase, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

I have a project which have SCM Implementation with Subversion and now I want (have) to use ClearCase as new repository. I'm having problems with scm configuration in the pom.xml, I have something like this:

```
...
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://url/to/my/repository/</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://url/to/my/repository/</developerConnection>
  <url>http://url/to/my/repository/</url>
</scm>
...
```

Now, I have to adapt this to ClearCase. I've been looking for information on the Internet and I've seen this url: http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html but I'm unable to manage it, I've tried this:

```
...
<scm>
  <connection>scm:clearcase:load /MY_VOB/my/folder/</connection>
  <!--<connection>scm:clearcase:load:/MY_VOB/my/folder:stream_name</connection>-->
  <developerConnection>scm:clearcase:load /MY_VOB/my/folder/</developerConnection>
  <!--<developerConnection>scm:clearcase:load:/MY_VOB/my/folder:stream_name</developerConnection>-->
  <url>http://url/to/my/repository/</url>
</scm>
...
```

The lines commented are other options, but I'm not sure if I'm doing well, can anybody guide me?

Thanks in advance.
Greetings.

UPDATE:

I've tried with, and I have a new problem :S:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:clearcase:MY_VIEW:MY_VOB:STREAM_NAME</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:clearcase:MY_VIEW:MY_VOB:STREAM_NAME</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

I've launched `mvn relase:prepare` and I get these errors:

```
[INFO] The SCM URL contains unused parameter : STREAM_NAME
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The cleartool command failed.
Command output:
"cleartool" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

We are using ClearCase Remote Client 8 and it seems not to use `cleartool` command but `rcleartool`.

Could you help in my SCM configuration? Is there any way to use `rcleartool` instead of `cleartool`?

Thanks in advance.
Greetings.

Comment: Are you using ClearCase UCM?

Comment: @VonC Yes, we are using UCM.

Comment: Then the :stream_name would matter.

Comment: @VonC I've just updated the post.

Comment: I have updated my answer: that old scm plugin isn't made to work with a ClearCase/ClearTeam 8.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <developerConnection>scm:clearcase:load /MY_VOB/my/folder/</developerConnection>
```

It means you have a ClearCase vob `/MY_VOB` (on Windows), or if you are on Unix `/vobs/MY_VOB`, with your project sources already added to source control in `/MY_VOB/my/folder/`.

In that context, I don't think `<url>http://url/to/my/repository/</url>` has any meaning for ClearCase.

However, that plugin is only made to work with a **full ClearCase installation (7.x)**, not with ClearTeam 8.x, which doesn't have cleartool, but only `rcleartool` (like [I mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269319/6309)).