# Code Coverage on New Code with ClaearCase 8 and SonarQube 5

Tags: code-coverage, clearcase, sonarqube-5.0

We are using SonarQube 5.0 to do code analysis on our java project and using JaCoCo to generate coverage report. The SCM used is clearcase 8.

We would like to use the Sonar ClearCase plugin in order to get the code coverage on the new code. However it fails saying it cannot find cleartool command. Since we are using ClearCase 8, we use rcleartool instead of cleartool as commandline utility.

Is there any way to find the code coverage on new code with ClearCase 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar case in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26121011/6309).
There is no direct solution beside updating the [Sonar ClearCase plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/ClearCase+Plugin).

You could *try* and install a wrapper called `cleartool`, which would call `rcleartool`, but there is no guarantee that all the options used by the plugin (for calling cleartool commands) can be used as-is for `rcleartool` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Machine from where you are running the sonar and jenkins should have clearcase installed and running in console.

you can check it with *cleartool -ver command*

if you have installed the clear case and it is not working then provide the path in enviorment variable.

Download and compile from: [github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase](http://Download%20and%20compile%20from:%20github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase)

Then put the jar in the **sonarqube-version\extensions\downloads** and restart the sonarqube it will install the plugin.

and in the sonar project setting you have to provide the 
**sonar.scm.provider=clearcase**