# How to download a file from ClearCase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, clearcase

Hi ClearCase Experts,

I just want to download a the latest version of a file from Clear Case for which I have the complete path & Clear Case View Name. Also we can safely assume that there is only one branch.

I looked for Clear Tool Commands [HERE](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ClearcaseCommands.html) but, non of them seems useful,for my purpose.

I don't want to do a checkout/check-in etc. I just want the latest version of file. Though, the requirement is fairly simple. I am not able to get this done because I don't see any direct way to do this.

Please Help.

Additional Info:
 I am using Visual studio 2012(C#,ASP.NET) with Clear Case Addons.

Any help appreciated!!.

Answer (score 2):

On way is to use [`cleartool get`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm).

> Use the get command to copy a specified version of a file element into your snapshot view.
>   You must issue the get command from the root directory of a snapshot view or any directory below it.

Example:

> On a Windows system, copy `\dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2` into the `C:\build directory`.

```
cleartool get -to C:\build\foo.c.temp \dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2
```

This is using the ClearCase **extended path** for accessing a given version, as illustrated in "[In ClearCase, how can I view old version of a file in a static view, from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/177350/6309)".
That other answer points to a way to access the content of a file with:

```
cleartool find yourFile -ver 'brtype(aBranch) && version(.../aBranch/LATEST) && ! version(.../aBranch/0)' -exec 'cleartool diff -ser empty "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'
```

That would look specifically for the LATEST version of a file on a given branch.

Comment: This command works in cmd windows 10 `cleartool get -to C:\build\foo.c.temp \dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2`

Comment: @Alper Yes, a CMD is indeed the kind of environment I used when I wrote this answer.