# Using ClearCase tool or java code, how to get the entire version of a particular file?

Tags: clearcase

I need to get the version (entire version like `main/branch1/branch2/1`) of a particular file using ClearCase tool or java code.

Can some one please help me on this ?

Comment: Describing the actual problem's context might help a lot...

Comment: I have a file abc.java ... it is might be in multiple branches say abc, xyz, mno... now i want to give input as abc.java (with full path) and want to check if that file has a different version in all the branches or the same version ...

Answer (score 1):

The command to use is [`cleartool get`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-16&lang=en):

> On a UNIX or Linux system, copy `/dev/hello_world/foo.c@@/main/2` into the current directory.

```
 cleartool get -to foo.c.temp /dev/hello_world/foo.c@@/main/2
```

> On a Windows system, copy `\dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2` into the `C:\build` directory.

```
 cleartool get -to C:\build\foo.c.temp \dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2
```

You can see more at "[In ClearCase, how can I view old version of a file in a static view, from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/177350/6309)":

- `cleartool get` don't do stdout (it only copies to a file)
- in a dynamic view, you can directly access any version you want

  ```
  cd /view/MyView/vobs/myVobs/myPath/myFile@@/main/[...]/maBranch
  cat 1
  ```