# How do I check out from an ancestor that is not the latest ancestor in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, ancestor, version-tree

## Background

I have a version tree that looks like this for a directory element:

```
[myView] --> A  --> B --> C
```

It is currently looking at Version B of the directory.  I want to make changes from the point of view of B.  However, when I run a [`ct co`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm), it will automatically do this:

```
[myView] --> A --> B --> C --> Checkedout
```

Instead of what I want below:

```
[myView] --> A --> B --> C
                   |
               Checkedout
```

## Question

How can I checkout directly from an intermediate ancestor in Clearcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cleartool checkout](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm) page has this example:

> Check out an old version of the file hello.h, using an extended path name to indicate the version. (Before you check in your revised version, you must perform a merge.)

```
cleartool checkout –c "attempt fix of old bug" -version hello.h@@\main\1
Checked out "hello.h" from version "\main\1".
```

So using an [extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309) (that [I used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/177350/6309)), you can checkout any version, but the checking will create a new version after C, by merging it with C.

This is best done in a dynamic view, where all pathnames are available.